# If/else loop executes both conditions

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-chrome-extension

OK, so I have the following code. The idea is to check if a page exists, if not, open a new tab. If exists, navigate to it.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  function check() {
        chrome.tabs.query(
            {currentWindow: true, url: 'https://www.google.com/*'},
            function(tabs) {
            tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
              console.log('Tab ID, URL: ', tab.id, ' ', tab.url);
                  if(tab.url !== '')
                  {
                    var updateProperties = {"active": true};
                    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, updateProperties, function(tab){ });
                    console.log('Assign true to functon');
                    return true;
                  }
            });
        });
      };

      if(check() === true) {
        console.log('Function is true, do nothing')
      }
      else {
        console.log('Function is false, open page')
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://www.google.com"});
      }
});
```

The first part works correctly, but the second one executes both true and false sections. It's like it executes the if/else statement before the function?

Comment: I would have thought the lack of a `return` statement in your `check()` function would hint towards something being very wrong here.

Comment: only way it is possible is if your listener is bound to 2 different elements and called for each of them for the same event.

Comment: It definitely *doesn't* execute both branches. In fact, using *that* code, it definitely never executes the `if` branch, because `check` never returns a value, so `check() === true` will never be true. If you're seeing "Function is true, do nothing" in the console, it's not coming from that code.

Comment: Also, beware that based on the fact it accepts a callback rather than returning an array, it would seem [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) is *asynchronous* (although irritatingly it doesn't actually say that in the documentation). That means `check` **cannot** return a flag for whether the tab exists, [see this question's answers for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). You'd want your create logic *inside* the `query` callback.

Comment: just want to add that chrome.tabs.query is asynchronous, you're thinking as your code is synchronous

Comment: @Karim: Thanks for confirming that, I'll close as a duplicate. Odd the docs don't say so explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues in the code:

1. `check` never returns anything, so `check() === true` will never be true. If you're seeing "Function is true, do nothing" in the console, it isn't coming from that code.
2. `check` **cannot** return anything useful, because [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) is asynchronous*.

So we get rid of `check` entirely and move the create logic *into* the callback:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        currentWindow: true,
        url: 'https://www.google.com/*'
    }, function(tabs) {
        const tab = tabs.find(tab => tab.url !== '');
        if (tab) {
            const updateProperties = {
                "active": true
            };
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, updateProperties, function(tab) {});
        } else {
            chrome.tabs.create({
                url: "https://www.google.com"
            });
        }
    }
});
```

A couple of side notes because I haven't written a Chrome extension in a long time:

1. Do you really need to search `tabs`? Given that you're passing `url` into `query`, wouldn't `if (tabs.length)` tell you the tab already exists?
2. Do you really need to pass the no-op function into `chrome.tabs.update`?

---

* <s>I assume it is, because it accepts a callback it calls rather than returning the array. Irritatingly, the documentation doesn't actually say that.</s> Karim has [confirmed it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845254/if-else-loop-executes-both-conditions/43845459?noredirect=1#comment74726587_43845254) in the comments, I'll trust him. :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you add callbacks, the return value doesn't come back directly in the function response - so in your case, `check()` returns nothing. The callback used inside `check()` returns a value, but this value isn't actually returned by the function, it essentially goes nowhere. There are at least 2 possible solutions to this:

#### 1. put the `if/else` inside the callback, and run the function once independently:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  function check() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        currentWindow: true,
        url: 'https://www.google.com/*'
      },
      function(tabs) {
        tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
          console.log('Tab ID, URL: ', tab.id, ' ', tab.url);
          if (tab.url !== '') {
            var updateProperties = {
              "active": true
            };
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, updateProperties, function(tab) {});
            console.log('Assign true to functon');
            // right here!
            console.log('Function is true, do nothing')
          } else {
            // and here!
            console.log('Function is false, open page')
            chrome.tabs.create({
              url: "https://www.google.com"
            });
          }
        });
      });
  };
  // execute it once
  check();
});
```

#### 2. use a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  function check() {
    // return the promise
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      chrome.tabs.query({
          currentWindow: true,
          url: 'https://www.google.com/*'
        },
        function(tabs) {
          tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
            console.log('Tab ID, URL: ', tab.id, ' ', tab.url);
            if (tab.url !== '') {
              var updateProperties = {
                "active": true
              };
              chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, updateProperties, function(tab) {});
              console.log('Assign true to functon');
              resolve('pass any extra success info you might need here');
            } else {
              reject('pass any extra rejection info you might need here')
            }
          });
        });
    })
  };

  // promise usage
  check().then(function(msg) {
    console.log('Function is true, do nothing. Extra info:', msg)
  }).catch(function(msg) {
      console.log('Function is false, open page. Extra info:', msg)
      chrome.tabs.create({
        url: "https://www.google.com"
      });
    }
  })
});
```